# Get Command Line of a java process

Tags: java, command-line, process-explorer

As we all know all java processes appear in task manager as javaw.exe. I want to get command line of all such java processes.  A tool called [ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) does the same thing but it displays all that in a GUI and i am looking at a programming solution for the same.

Here is a snapshot from [ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) tool.

[image]

Any ideas??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get it with [WMIC](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742610.aspx)

```
C:\> wmic process where(name="javaw.exe") get commandline
```

Answer (score 1):

If a command line solution helps **and** you have Windows Powershell available, you can use something like

```
PS> $c = Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "name='javaw.exe'" | select-Object CommandLine
PS> $x.CommandLine
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe" "-Djava.class.path=C:\\PROGRA~2\\Java\\jre7\\classes" ...
```

Answer (score 1):

use the command `jps` to find java processes

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jps.html

Comment: You won't get the "command line" used  with the full path of the JRE.

Answer (score 1):

With **command prompt** in windows, you can run below command

```
wmic process where(name="javaw.exe") get commandline
```

Sample Output with Command Prompt

```
CommandLine

"C:\Users\Public\agent\jre\bin\javaw.exe" -cp .\agent-jar-with-dependencies.jar com.agent.Runner
```

With **powershell prompt**, you can run below command

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Process -Filter "Name='javaw.exe'" | select-Object CommandLine
```

Sample Output with Powershell command

```
CommandLine
-----------
"C:\Users\Public\agent\jre\bin\javaw.exe" -cp .\agent-jar-with-dependencies.jar com.agent.Runner
```